# Codeigniter cart - add ketchup on pizza

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm building pizzeria app in CI using cart library.
For some products (pizza, salad...) there is an option to add ingredients.
This is what I have:

Add_to _cart buton

```
<button class="but_add_cart"
        data-qty="1" 
        data-productid="<?php echo $food_item->item_id; ?>" 
        data-productname="<?php echo $food_item->item_name; ?>" 
        data-productprice="<?php echo $food_item->item_price; ?>"
        data-adds="<?php echo $food_item->item_price; ?>
```

With jquery I'm calling ajax

```
$('.but_add_cart').click(function(){

        allVals = []

        $('#chk :checked').each(function() {
           allVals.push($(this).val());
         });
        // here I'm getting all ingredients from checkboxes and push to array

        var product_id = $(this).data("productid");
        var description = $(this).data("description");
        var product_name = $(this).data("productname");
        var product_price = $(this).data("productprice");
        var product_qty = $(this).data("qty");


        if(product_id != '' && product_id > 0) 
            {
                $.ajax({
                url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>menu/add",
                type:"POST",
                async: true,
                data:{product_id:product_id, description:description, product_name:product_name, product_qty:product_qty, product_price:product_price, allVals:allVals},
                success:function(data)
                    {
                        $('#cart_details').html(data);

                    }
                });

            } 
        else
            {
                alert("Please Enter quantity");
            }
});
```

and add function is:

```
function add()
    {
        $data = array(
            "id"  => $_POST["product_id"],
            "qty"  => $_POST["product_qty"],
            "price"  => $_POST["product_price"],
            "name"  => $_POST["product_name"],
            "description"  => $_POST["description"],
            "allVals"  => $_POST["allVals"]
        );

            print_r($data);

            //$this->cart->insert($data);
            //echo $this->view();

    }
```

from print_r I have this array

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [qty] => 1
    [price] => 19.90
    [name] => Pepperoni Pizza
    [description] => Extra-virgin olive oil, garlic, mozzarella cheese
    [allVals] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 4
            [3] => 6
        )
)
```

Now, in the cart, I want to group Pepperoni pizza with ingredients (2, 3, 4, 6) as one item. If I add one more Pepperoni pizza but with different ingredients, it should be separate item in the cart. I tried to add some random number to rowid but it gives me some error.

Also, every ingredients coast so I have to add these prices to subtotal price for each item in the basket.

I know problem is quite complex but I would like to know if my approach is good or there is a better way to to do this?

Comment: As an Italian, I really can't see how ketchup could ever go on pizza XD

Comment: Is this in Brazil, I thought we were the only ones to put ketchup on pizza...

Comment: Hehehe, believe or not, people put ketchup on pizza, including me :) And I'm just opposite to Italy in Serbia

Comment: What is the specific code related question?

Comment: **after** pizza and side ingredients/stuff is set, why don't you ask/offer to *2 or *3 the same item ? if yes, push the array `qty` +1 else add another item in array, no ? As pizza with different ingredients can be seen as different dishes ? beside that, this question is blatlantly off-topic as pizza should **never ever** end under some ketchup ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the answer here not to use the ingredients as the key?

```
asort($_POST['allVals']);
$key = implode('',$_POST['allVals']);
```

Combine the Product ID and $key and see if that product exists in the cart. If it does then update the quantity. Your ingredients are your unique key?